# Compare two uneven json array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi I have two uneven JSON array which I am decoding in php. First array has 2 values and other has 3 values now I want to search for an 'id' number from first array to second array and display the names. Is there any way to do it? I would appreciate your help. Thank you

Here is the example of my first array

```
[
{
    "id": 5,
    "pb_first_name": "Respect",
    "pb_last_name": "Respect"
},
{
    "id": 41,
    "pb_first_name": "Master",
    "pb_last_name": "Master"
}
```

]

Here is the second JSON array

```
[
{
    "id": 5,
    "type": "Suite",
    "description": "",
    "number": "105",
    "floor": 1
},
{
   "id": 23,
    "type": "Suite",
    "description": "",
    "number": "220",
    "floor": 2
},
{
   "id": 41,
    "type": "Penthouse",
    "description": "",
    "number": "410",
    "floor": 4
}
```

]

Comment: Question isn't exactly clear. What are you trying to get from the arrays? Could to elaborate?

Comment: json is irrelevant. if you've decoded them, then they're PHP arrays. there's no such thing as a "json array". there's just json strings, which ENCODE arrays/objects/values.

Comment: K i have updated my question. I have to display names with same ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_diff`, `array_intersect`, `in_array` or `array_search`. Since you haven't mentioned any code, I don't know which one would best suit your need.

Manuals:
[array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php),
[array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php),
[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php),
[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

**Edit:**

```
$arr1 = array(...); // 1st array
$arr2 = array(...); //2nd array
foreach($arr2 as $v) {
  foreach($arr1 as $m) {
   if ($v['id'] == $m['id'])
    echo $m[pb_first_name'] . " " . $m['pb_last_name'];
 }
}
```